# How to write the code without disturbing page data to get the previous page values?

Tags: asp.net

[image: gridview dropdown]

Hi,

I am taking gridview, with in grid use the dropdown based on customer retrieve the database values in dropdown, but my issue is with in dropdown **"Add New Item"** (second column)is taking, so customer select the that field open the new page and add the values, after adding the item automatically close the page and mainpage dropdown automatically added without disturbing the other values how is it possible?

```
  I am using ASP.NET2.0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to make sure I'm on the right page:  You have a drop down list with items.  Picking an item from the list shows data related to that item in a GridView.  Picking the second item on the list, "Add New Item", shows a different window which allows you to add a new item.  You don't want the process of adding a new item to interupt any activities going on on the GridView page.  After adding a new item you want the items listed in the DropDownList to automatically update.

I would suggest using AJAX with a Modal dialog box for adding the item and a web service/page method to handle the actual adding process behind the scenes.  Then use javascript to add the new item to the dropdownlist.